# Nothng Written to Serial when using sprintf

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, string

I'm using `sprintf` to use a format specifier `myTemplate` with some strings. The result will then be written to Serial. Although the sketch compiles fine, it does not write any thing to the serial, nothing is seen in the Serial monitor.

Is `sprintf` being used wrongly here?

```
char* result;
char* myTemplate;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    myTemplate = "Welcome %s. You have slept %s times";
    sprintf(result, myTemplate, "Jane", "many");
    Serial.println(result);
    Serial.println("hello");

}
```

---

When I try the follwing sketch and write something to the Serial monitor, I receive gibberish echoed back to me!  Why is this?

**Sketch**

```
char received;
char* message = "";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

    // Echos back
    if(Serial.available() > 0) {
        received = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(message);


        if(received == '\n') {
            message = "";
        }  else {
            message += received;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually allocate any memory to `result`?

Comment: define 'gibberish'. Can you give some examples of what you are receiving? Have you got the monitor on 9600 as well? You realise you're `Serial.print`ing `message` before you're allocating your read to it? And that at the end of the read there is possibly a new line which clears your message anyway, so it's never going to be seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `sprintf()`, you need to have some space allocated for it to write the result to. At the moment, you're just passing an uninitialised pointer (`result`), meaning the behaviour of `sprintf()` is undefined. It might appear to work under some circumstances, but not others (and even if it did seem to work, it could have some nasty side effects on other parts of your code).

The simplest approach is to allocate a static `char` buffer. You need to be sure it's big enough to contain all of the text you want it to store though (plus an extra null character at the end).

For example:

```
char* myTemplate = "";
char result[64] = {0};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    myTemplate = "Welcome %s. You have slept %s times";

    sprintf(result, myTemplate, "Jane", "many");
    Serial.println(result);
    Serial.println("hello");
}
```

As a side note, it's usually a good idea to initialise your variables. This is especially true for pointers.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't quite *always* good to initialize them. Initializing them (or leaving them with the default value) will add prologue code to set/clear them even if the original value is never used; to prevent this declare the variable as being uninitialized, e.g. `char *result __attribute__ ((section (".noinit")));`. See the ["Memory Sections" section of the AVR Libc documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/mem_sections.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you. When I try to empty out `message` using `message=""`, I get the error in the (updated) question. Whats the proper way to clear a buffer?

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Why do you need to clear it?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I updated the code in the question to show why I'm clearing it, thanks!

Comment: Oh boy... Unfortunately string handling in C is not quite as simple as you try to make it. Consider using [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) or [`String`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It does work with String, but I'm reading lots of tips about how String is dynamically allocated and will encounter errors after some time.

Comment: Handling C strings is a bit out of scope for this site. Consider reading through [C string questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+string) for some insight on how they work.